Difference between direct image sheaf and double dual of direct image
Let $f:X\to S$ be a smooth surjective morphism between smooth projective varieties. Let $D$ be a (Cartier) divisor on $X$, then in general $f_*\mathcal{O}_X(D)$ needs not to be locally free. However it's torsion free so that we have a canonical injection from $$f_* \mathcal{O}_X(D) \hookrightarrow \widehat{f_*  \mathcal{O}_X(D)}$$where $\widehat{f_*  \mathcal{O}_X(D)}$ denotes the double dual of $f_*\mathcal{O}_X(D)$. I read in some references that without lose of generality, we can assume that there exist an $f$-effective divisor $E$ such that $$f_* \mathcal{O}_X(D+E) \cong \widehat{f_*  \mathcal{O}_X(D)}.$$

The question is how can I prove this result. I know that the canonical inclusion above is isomorphic to codimension 1, so that maybe we need to pull back the place that not isomorphic and it can produce the effective divisor $E$, but I have no idea how to give a proof of it?

By Corollary 1.7 in [Hartshorne, Robin. Stable reflexive sheaves. Math. Ann. 254 (1980), no. 2, 121--176] the sheaf $f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is reflexive, hence the morphism to its double dual is an isomorphism.

Thank you Sasha, Merry Christmas.
